# Cannot debug onPostExecute within Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am trying to debug an AsyncTask within Android Studio, however the debugger is not allowing me to step into the `onPostExecute()` method and I'm not sure why. I am sure that it is executing because I put a Toast that shows, however I want to debug within there and for some reason I can't. Is a reason why this would be?

```
private class LoadObject extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context context;
    String postAddress;


    public LoadObject(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "OnPostExecute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        functionToExecute();

        if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        bLoaded = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            postApi.postAPI(postAddress);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you go to onPreExecute first and to doInBackground after that?

Comment: Yes I do. Both of which I can debug as well. But just not onPostExecute

Comment: and do executing of doInBackground end successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the line `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` In your `onPostExecute()` method. This will wait for the debugger to attach to your separate thread, and then it will return once the debugger is attached. Then try putting a break point right after this line and it should hit.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger()

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to add `execute()`, otherwise you instantiate, but do not trigger the async task:
`LoadObject(this).execute()`